# Yeoman, Angular Generator, and Karma Test not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I'm trying to use Yeoman with the [angular-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) to start a new application.

I run this command (according to the docs) to start a new app:

`yo angular my-app-name`

All dependencies have been download and if I run

`grunt serve`

my base app shows up in browser and everything look to work fine.
The problem starts when I try to run:

`grunt test`

I get an error : `Warning: Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.`

So I've added these line:

```
"grunt-karma": "*",
"generator-karma": "*"
```

in my `packeage.json` file, remove the `node_modules` folder and runned `` `npm install ``. I was hping to solving the issue but now i get the error:

```
loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client'
Warning: Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've tried to google a bit but I can't find anything about. I'm running MacOsX 10.8.5 and node v0.10.0 . Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been problems with Karma and angular-generator. Are you running the latest version of the generator?

Not sure what caused the failure, but sometimes there are issues installing karma dependencies. Try running:

```
npm install grunt-karma karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor karma-ng-scenario --save-dev
```

And if that doesn't work then workaround you can use for now is to add the following dependencies to your package.json after it failed installing:

```
"karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
"grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
"karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.2",
"karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
"requirejs": "~2.1.9",
"karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
"karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.1",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.1",
"karma": "~0.10.8",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0"
```

Then run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

the yeoman distribution (December 2014) misses the library js files because karma.conf.is in test points to bower_components which could be wrong. change the karma.conf.is file and replace bower_components to node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

the cause of the problem occurs in an earlier phase.
The solution is not to change the kama config file but execute the command:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://